# Hadoop cluster over Docker. Zookeeper start service command not working from outside container but works from inside

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I've a hadoop cluster working on docker for testing. I've installed zookeeper but I can't start zookeeper service from outside docker with docker exec command.

After installing zookeeper in the hadoop cluster, I'm able to start each zookeeper node connecting to each of them and executing: `bin/zkServer.sh start`

But when I try to launch the command from outside docker, with the
`docker exec -u hadoop -it nodemaster  /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start`  it fails.

Looks like any config (CLASSPATH) variables are not properly launched with docker exec

The only way to add config parameters to the zkServer.sh command is using the -config, but it only puts the zookeeper conf file.

I've executed zkServer.sh with the print-cmd option from inside and outside, and from outside the CLASSPATH seems not to be the OK.

Those are the zkServer commands working fine inside docker:

```
hadoop@nodemaster:~$ /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
hadoop@nodemaster:~$ /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Stopping zookeeper ... STOPPED
hadoop@nodemaster:~$ exit
And this is the same command launched from outside docker:
==> $ docker exec -u hadoop -it nodemaster  /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start

ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... FAILED TO START
```

This is the zkServer.sh command with the --print-cmd option:

**Inside container:**

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
"/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java"  -Dzookeeper.log.dir="/home/hadoop/zookeeper/logs"     -Dzookeeper.log.file="zookeeper--server-nodemaster.log" -Dzookeeper.root.logger="INFO,CONSOLE"     -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -cp "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/classes: ...
 ... CLASSPATH WITH ALL THE STUFF .....
/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/hadoop/hive/lib/*.jar" -Xmx1000m   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg" > "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper--server-nodemaster.out" 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

**Outside container:**

```
 docker exec -u hadoop -it nodemaster  /home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh --config /home/hadoop/zookeeper/conf print-cmd

ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
"/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java"  -Dzookeeper.log.dir="/home/hadoop/zookeeper/logs"     -Dzookeeper.log.file="zookeeper--server-nodemaster.log" -Dzookeeper.root.logger="INFO,CONSOLE"     -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'     -cp "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/classes:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-server/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper/conf:" -Xmx1000m   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg" > "/home/hadoop/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper--server-nodemaster.out" 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

So, it looks like the classpath is not correct when launching the outsider command... 
I've tried to put the command inside a script, but same error.

```
docker exec -u hadoop -it nodemaster /home/hadoop/zookeeper/zoo_init.sh

ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hadoop/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
```

Comment: You should never be starting services inside a container using `docker exec`; when you `docker run` the container it should start the single service it's running.  In a typical Docker-based setup you'd have some number of ZooKeeper containers, separate Hadoop namenode and datanode containers, and so on.

Comment: (Consider how you're going to restart this if there's a new version of Hadoop and you need to delete and recreate the container on a new image.)

Comment: Thanks @David, I'll give a try to launch two separate group of containers for Hadoop and Zookeeper. My first idea was to keep all of them together in order to improve performance.